# Question about $2p-1$ and $2p+1$, where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $x+1$ be any prime greater than $3$.

By Bertrand's Postulate, there is at least one prime between $\frac{x}{2}$ and $x$.

Let $\{p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n\}$ be the primes between $\frac{x}{2}$ and $x$

In all cases that I've checked, there exists $p_i$ in this set where either $2p_i-1$ or $2p_i+1$ is a prime.

Is this always true?

Comment: I am using Bertrand's Postulate to show that $\{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n\}$ is not an empty set.

Comment: There are no counterexamples for $x/2$ under one million

Comment: Believable, but I doubt there is a known proof. After all, it is not even known whether there are infinitely many Sophie Germain primes.

Comment: Although sophie germain primes are a little more restrictive than these primes, I called these  supa-primes. Although I see your point, if there was a finite amount of primes so that $2p+1$ is prime there would probably be a finite amount of primes so that $2p-1$ is prime. Where here probably means it would make sense to my brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure it is open.  We know Sophie Germain is open, and [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&s=bl&ots=TkjtfVCKpy&sig=5KNye_coFQR66mizxFJcCa8ljE8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=INusVK-4HsTboATA1IHQBg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwBA) mentions a theorem of Chen regarding the $2 \cdot p - 1$ case which is strictly weaker (suggesting that infinite $2 \cdot p - 1$ primes is open).  Unless there is some way we can prove the disjunction without proving either case individually then this is also open.